# Overriding reCAPTCHA CSS

Tags: css, recaptcha

I'm using [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha), and the textarea for `recaptcha_challenge_field` is appearing in the middle of the recaptcha box overlapping other things. I found that it's because of this style:

```
.recaptchatable #recaptcha_response_field {
    position: absolute!important;
```

when I set `position` to `static` in Chrome, it looks fine. However, I can't figure out how to overwrite that CSS option.

I tried:

- adding this to my own CSS:

  ```
  .recaptchatable #recaptcha_response_field {
       position: static !important;
  }
  ```
- adding another entry in my CSS with the name `.recaptcha_text`

  - calling it via div class (wrapping around textarea)
  - calling it via p class (wrapping around textarea)
  - adding `position: static!important;` to the standard `<textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" ...>` tag

However, I can't get my css to overwrite that position: static!important; that comes over with the script:

```html
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=your_public_key">
</script>
<noscript>
  <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=your_public_key"
     height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
  <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
  <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge">
</noscript>
```

Can someone please help with what I'm doing wrong?  Thank you!

Comment: It should be sandboxed so verify its not one of your styles causing the problem, e.g. try to repro on a blank page with only recaptcha. Otherwise is recaptcha css in its own file? Replace it with a local modified copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From testing here: http://jsbin.com/otihuk/edit#html,live (the *test* only seems to work in WebKit browsers)

This looks like a simple CSS specificity issue. The reCAPTCHA CSS is loaded after yours, and both your selector and theirs have equal specificity (and both have `!important` in the declaration), and so because theirs is specified last, it wins.

You can fix it by making your selector more specific than theirs:

```
#recaptcha_area #recaptcha_response_field {
    position: static !important;
}
```

I've added that in my demo above, and I can see by inspecting the `#recaptcha_response_field` element that the computed value of the `position` property is now indeed `static`.

Comment: for some reason when i put it in my css file, it did not work, but when i added it directly in the head of the html it worked.  thanks!